# Using type() of Sequence as constructor for a type-preserving map yields "Unexpected argument" warning

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a function that applies some mapping transformation to a generic `Sequence` of items. Because my input can be any type of `Sequence` (`list`, `tuple`, etc.), I want to dynamically return a `Sequence` that is of the same type as my input.

For this I can use the following setup:

```
def bar(x: X) -> Y:
    ..

def foo(seq: Sequence[X]) -> Sequence[Y]:
    seq_type = type(seq)

    return seq_type(bar(x) for x in seq)
```

My IDE (PyCharm) complains, however, that the generator argument to `seq_type` is an `Unexpected argument`. N.B: this code works and does exactly what I want, it's mainly this warning that makes me wonder whether this is the way to go.

So concretely: how should I go about preserving the type of my sequence in a Pythonesque way, or should I simply ignore my IDE here?

Comment: FYI: `seq_type(map(bar, seq))` yields the same error, the fact that I provide a generator as argument here is not the issue at hand.